# MD5 Transforming uint8_t to a string

Tags: c, md5

I am using the Md5 C code on wikipedia

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

if (argc < 2) {
    printf("usage: %s 'string'\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
}

char *msg = argv[1];
size_t len = strlen(msg);

// benchmark
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    md5(msg, len);
}

//var char digest[16] := h0 append h1 append h2 append h3 //(Output is in little-endian)
uint8_t *p;

// display result

p=(uint8_t *)&h0;
printf("%2.2x%2.2x%2.2x%2.2x", p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], h0);

p=(uint8_t *)&h1;
printf("%2.2x%2.2x%2.2x%2.2x", p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], h1);

p=(uint8_t *)&h2;
printf("%2.2x%2.2x%2.2x%2.2x", p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], h2);

p=(uint8_t *)&h3;
printf("%2.2x%2.2x%2.2x%2.2x", p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], h3);
puts("");

return 0;
```

}

That is the code.I already have some knowledge how it works, and I need to transform the result of the MD5 to a string.
Is this possible?

Basically I would need to convert p=(uint8_t *)&h0; each one of them to a char[] and concat them, in other word, having the whole MD5 code in one char[]. Is this correct/possible?

I spent my whole day yestarday tying to find this and the best I got is how to trasform a unit32_t using sprinft, and it does work. but for unit8_t it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each 8 bit number should be printed with `%02x`.

- The leading `0` means that the number will be shown with leading zeros
- The `2` means that the width is two hex characters
- The `x` means print the number in hex.

So the first instance would be:

```
p = (uint8_t *) &h0;
printf("%02x%02x%02x%02x", p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3]);
```

Comment: So if I do a sprintf( buffer, "%02x%02x%02x%02x", p), it works?

Comment: Question: how big should be buffer be so that the 8 bit's can be copying to it?

Comment: The official version of this is to use the `PRIx8` macro for printing `uint8_t`. Something like `printf("%" PRIx8, p[0])`.